# React render function keeps being called

Tags: reactjs, state, render

The render function in my React app keeps being called which causes problems. I have a function that displays some of the state objects but it fails because it keeps being called. At least that's what I think is happening.

Other errors include uncaught promises and updating the state on an unmounted component. I think these are merely symptoms of the constant rerendering though but I can't be sure. I've pasted all of the relevant code below in the hopes that someone can figure it out and help me.

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { FlexyFlipCard } from 'flexy-flipcards';
import Bingo from '../utils/Bingo';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    console.log('constructor - This happens 1st.');

    this.state = {
      loading: 'initial',
      data: '',
      card: {},
      tiles: {}
    };

  }

  componentWillMount() {

    console.log('componentWillMount - This happens 2nd.');

    this.setState({ profile: {} });
    const { userProfile, getProfile } = this.props.auth;
    if (!userProfile) {
      getProfile((err, profile) => {
        this.setState({
          profile,
          loading: 'profile'
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ profile: userProfile });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    console.log('componentDidMount - This happens 5th.');

    const cardId = 14;

    this.setState({ loading: 'true' });
    this.fetchCard(cardId)
    .then((card) => {
      console.log('componentDidMount - This happens 9th.');
      this.setState({ tiles: card }, function() {
        this.setState({ loading: 'complete' })
      });
    });
  }

  fetchCard(cardId) {

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Bingo.getTiles(cardId).then(card => {
        console.log('fetchCard - This happens 8th (after Bingo.getTiles).');
        resolve(card);
      });
    });

    console.log('fetchCard - This happens 6th.');
    return promise;
  }

  renderCards() {

    console.log('renderCards');

    if (this.state.tiles.length > 0) {
      return this.state.tiles.map(tile => {
        return (
          <div
            className="item"
            key={tile[0].id}>
              <FlexyFlipCard
                  frontBackgroundColor="#000034"
                  backBackgroundColor="#000034"
              >
                <div ref="flipper">
                  <h3>{tile[0].name}</h3>
                  <br />
                  <button className="select">Select artist</button>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <h4>
                    <input type="radio"
                      name="artist1"
                      value={tile[0].artist_1}
                    />
                    {tile[0].artist_1}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio"
                      name="artist2"
                      value={tile[0].artist_2}
                    />
                    {tile[0].artist_2}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="radio"
                      name="artist3"
                      value={tile[0].artist_3}
                    />
                    {tile[0].artist_3}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div ref="flipper">
                      <button className="select"
                        onClick={this.submitArtist}>
                        Save artist
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </FlexyFlipCard>

          </div>
        );
      });
    }
  }

  render() {

    console.log('render - This happens 3rd - after componentWillMount');

    const { profile } = this.state;

    if (this.state.loading === 'initial') {
      console.log('render - This happens 4th - after the class is constructed.');
      return <h2>Intializing...</h2>;
    }


    if (this.state.loading === 'true') {
      console.log('render - This happens 7th - when waiting for data.');
      return (
        <div className="Card">
          <h2>Preparing your bingo card - please wait one moment</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }


    if (this.state.loading === 'complete') {
      console.log('render - This happens when???');
      return (
        <div className="Card">
          <h2>{profile.nickname + String.fromCharCode(39)}s Radio Bingo Board</h2>
          <div className="tileCard">
            <div className="item-list">
              {this.renderCards()}
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      );
    }

    console.log('render - This happens 8th - after I get data.');
    return (
      <div className="Card">
        Blank space
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

[image: first error]

[image: second error]

[image: third error]

[image: fourth error]

[image: fifth error]

Comment: The React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) say  componentwillreceiveprops is legacy and should not be used. That said, I notice componentWillMount is also legacy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my fetch response was an Object instead of an Array so I couldn't map through it. The error messages made me think it was a problem with render being called too many times though.

This simple piece of code corrected the issue by feeding the JSON into an array. Pity it took me about a week to figure it out.

```
Bingo.getTiles(cardId).then(response => {

  const card = Object.keys(response).map((index) => {
    const tile = [];
    tile.push(response[index]);
    return tile;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use setState it will render. Well not always, sometimes React will execute several setState actions in one.

I cannot read all the errors, but first one is because page is rendered in the moment when object doesn't exist, so it says cannot read property id of undefined. You can ask before rendering id object exists first. E.g. if(title) title.id etc.

If you need all the steps shown to user, than you have to assume that objects will not exist in certain situations and you always have to check whether object exist before calling the property.

Comment: The problem is the render is happening once I get a response from my database, not only when I setState.

Comment: Yes but how I see from you code, you setState when you get data from DB.I would use only componentDidMount, would remove componentWillMount, and put everything you need to setup there.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it turns out I wasn't using the right data structure. I was trying to map through an Object instead of an Array. Once I fixed that, it was all systems go.